# how to add a new source inside a conduit haskell

Tags: haskell, conduit

I have a problem with the following code using [`network-conduit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-conduit):

```
import Data.Conduit.List as CL
import Data.Conduit.Text as CT
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as S8
import qualified Data.Text as TT

mySource :: ResourceT m => Integer -> Source m Int
mySource i = {- function -} undefined

myApp :: Application
myApp src snk = 
    src $= CT.decode CT.ascii
        $= CL.map decimal
        $= CL.map {-problem here-}
        $$ src
```

in problem place I want to write something like

```
\t -> case t of
    Left err = S8.pack $ "Error:" ++ e
    Right (i,xs) = (>>>=) mySource 
                 {- or better: 
                   do 
                   (>>>=) mySource
                   (<<<=) T.pack xs
                  -}
```

where the `(>>>=)` function pushes `mySource` output to the next level and
      `(<<<=)` is sending function back to previous level

Comment: Does `conduit` support sending data upstream? I know `pipes` does. Maybe you'll need to use `pipes` for your use case.

Comment: A `Conduit` can push data back into its own input with `leftover`, but here, the `Conduit` wants to push input back into its upstream `Conduit`'s input, which is not possible.  A parser `Conduit` should be used in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The network chops up the byte stream into arbitrary `ByteString` chunks.  With the code above, those `ByteString` chunks will be mapped to chunks of `Text`, and each chunk of `Text` will be parsed as a `decimal`.  However, a string of decimal digits representing a single `decimal` may be split across two (or more) `Text` chunks.  Also, as you realize, using `decimal` gives you back the remainder of the `Text` chunk that didn't get parsed as part of the `decimal`, which you are trying to shove back into the input stream.

Both of these problems can be solved by using `Data.Conduit.Attoparsec. conduitParserEither` with `Data.Attoparsec.Text.decimal`.  Note that it is not sufficient to just parse `decimal`; you will also need to handle some kind of separator between `decimal`s.

It is also not possible to splice a `Source` from `CL.map`, since `CL.map`'s type signature is

```
map :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> Conduit a m b
```

The function you pass to `map` gets an opportunity to transform each input `a` into a single output `b`, not a stream of `b`'s.  To do that, you can use `awaitForever`, but you'll need to transform your `Source` into a general `Producer` with `toProducer` in order for the types to match.

However, in your code, you are trying to send parse errors downstream as `ByteString`'s, but the output of `mySource` as `Int`'s, which is a type error.  You must provide a stream of `ByteString` in both cases; the successful parse case can return a `Conduit` made by fusing other `Conduit`'s as long as it ends up with an output of `ByteString`:

```
...
$= (let f (Left err) = yield $ S8.pack $ "Error: " ++ show err
        f (Right (_, i)) = toProducer (mySource i) $= someOtherConduit
    in awaitForever f)
```

where `someOtherConduit` sinks the `Int`'s from `mySource`, and sources `ByteString`'s.

```
someOtherConduit :: Monad m => Conduit Int m ByteString
```

Finally, I believe you meant to connect the `snk` at the end of the pipe instead of the `src`.

Comment: The code was written for conduit-0.4 or some of the something like that, where there were no `Producers`, `Consumer`s and `Pipes` at all, the leftovers were not there as well. I don't have this problem around me for 5y or more and not sure if I'll be able to remember why I wanted to solve thing this way, and if answer covers the problem I actually had. It tells right things though so may be useful for people using conduits this days so I'm marking it as accepted.